# move overlay image on camera preview

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, surfaceholder, camera-overlay

I want overlay an image in live camera preview using surface view. There are lot of tutorial in  this case and my program run perfectly. Now i want add ability to move overlay image in live camera preview with touch event. I can't find any code or tutorial that explain that. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not use OpenGL and just float your overlay with opacity over surfaceView, you can set your own onDragListener() that handles android DragEvent( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/DragEvent.html) that can move the overlay detecting user's finger